# Main Activity won't communicate with Fragment 2

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I've managed to work out how to use an Interface java class to send information from two fragments (Fragment 1a and Fragment 1b) to Main Activity, however I'm having real difficulty sending information from Main Activity to another fragment (Fragment 2).  I've tried a dozen things but I keep getting a Null Pointer exception in Main Activity and Fragment 2 at the following points:

**Main Activity**:

```
        //Send data to Even Split Fragment 2
        evenSplit_CalculationFragment2.tellMeWhatEachPersonOwesES(eachPersonOwesESString);
```

**Fragment 2:**

```
public void tellMeWhatEachPersonOwesES (String eachPersonOwesThisESString) {

    amountEachPersonOwesES.setText(eachPersonOwesThisESString);

};
```

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.  Full code of Main Activity, Fragment 2 and the Communicator interface below:

Main Activity:

```
package apps.created.jay.splititapp;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Communicator  {

    Button nextButton, calculateButton, backButton;
    partySizeAndMethodFragment partySize_MethodFragment;
    evenSplitCalculationFragment1 evenSplit_CalculationFragment1;
    evenSplitCalculationFragment2 evenSplit_CalculationFragment2;
    byWhoHadWhatCalculationFragment1 byWhoHadWhat_CalculationFragment1;
    byWhoHadWhatCalculationFragment2 byWhoHadWhat_CalculationFragment2;
    String numberInPartyString;
    String splitMethodString;
    String billGrandTotalString;
    String eachPersonOwesESString;
    double numberInPartyDouble, eachPersonOwesESDouble, billGrandTotalDouble;
    TextView codeTesterView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Implement Initial Fragment (i.e. Set Party Size and Method of Split)
        FragmentManager splitItFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction splitItFragmentTransaction = splitItFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        partySize_MethodFragment = new partySizeAndMethodFragment();
        splitItFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, partySize_MethodFragment);
        splitItFragmentTransaction.commit();

        //Initialise Next Button
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next1button);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Initialise Calculate Button
        calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Initialise Back Button
        backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    //COMMUNICATIONS

    //Method of Split (from Party Size & Method Fragment)

    @Override
    public void respond(String splitMethodData) {

        splitMethodString = splitMethodData;

    }

    // Party Size (from Party Size & Method Fragment)

    @Override
    public void partyOfWhat(String numberInPartyData) {

        numberInPartyString = numberInPartyData;

    }

    // Total Bill (from Even Split Calculation Fragment 1)

    @Override
    public void billGrandTotal(String billGrandTotalData) {

        billGrandTotalString = billGrandTotalData;

    }


    //On Button Click

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        FragmentManager splitItFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction splitItFragmentTransaction = splitItFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if(v.getId() == R.id.next1button) {

            if (splitMethodString.equals("byWhoHadWhat")) {

                byWhoHadWhat_CalculationFragment1 = new byWhoHadWhatCalculationFragment1();
                splitItFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, byWhoHadWhat_CalculationFragment1);
                splitItFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                splitItFragmentTransaction.commit();

                //Replace Next Button with Calculate & Back Button
                nextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                calculateButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            } else if (splitMethodString.equals("evenly")) {

                //Replace Fragment

                evenSplit_CalculationFragment1 = new evenSplitCalculationFragment1();
                splitItFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, evenSplit_CalculationFragment1);
                splitItFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                splitItFragmentTransaction.commit();

                //Replace Next Button with Calculate & Back Button
                nextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                calculateButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }

        else if (v.getId() == R.id.backButton){

                splitItFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, partySize_MethodFragment);
                splitItFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                splitItFragmentTransaction.commit();

                //Replace Next Button with Calculate & Back Button
                nextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                calculateButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                backButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        else if (v.getId() == R.id.calculateButton){

            //Convert Strings pulled from Fragments into Doubles
            numberInPartyDouble = Double.parseDouble(numberInPartyString);

            billGrandTotalDouble = Double.parseDouble(billGrandTotalString.replace(",",""));

            eachPersonOwesESString = String.valueOf(billGrandTotalDouble/numberInPartyDouble);


            //Replace Even Split Fragment 1 with Even Split Fragment 2
            evenSplit_CalculationFragment2 = new evenSplitCalculationFragment2();
            splitItFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, evenSplit_CalculationFragment2);
            splitItFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            splitItFragmentTransaction.commit();

            //Send data to Even Split Fragment 2
            evenSplit_CalculationFragment2.tellMeWhatEachPersonOwesES(eachPersonOwesESString);

            //Hide Calculate Button
            calculateButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }

}
```

Fragment 2:

```
package apps.created.jay.splititapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Jay on 02/06/2015.
 */
public class evenSplitCalculationFragment2 extends Fragment {

    String eachPersonOwesThisESString;
    TextView amountEachPersonOwesES;
    View evenSplitView2;
    Communicator comm;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Define the View and inflate Fragment 2
        evenSplitView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.even_split_calculation_fragment_layout_2, container, false);
        return evenSplitView2;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        amountEachPersonOwesES = (TextView) evenSplitView2.findViewById(R.id.even_split_amount_due);
        comm = (Communicator) getActivity();
    }

    //COMMUNICATIONS

    //What Each Person Owes (from Main Activity)

    public void tellMeWhatEachPersonOwesES (String eachPersonOwesThisESString) {

        amountEachPersonOwesES.setText(eachPersonOwesThisESString);

    }




}
```

Interface:

```
public interface Communicator {

    public void respond (String data);
    public void partyOfWhat (String data);
    public void billGrandTotal (String data);

}
```

Comment: you use bundles between communication to fragments

Comment: Bundles are a great way to send and receive data.

Answer (score 0):

hava a look at this tutorial 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

You need a call back to be able to communicate between fragment and activity

this is a quick sample from google page:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    ...
}

public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    ...

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
        // Do something here to display that article
    }
}
```

I recommend you downloading the sample from the link above and have a play with it. it's very good.

I hope this helps you